# When sending datagram packets, the data of the packet is duplicated. (java)

Tags: java, udp, buffer, packet, datagram

UDPclient:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DatagramSocket socket;
    DatagramPacket packet;
    String str = "";
    byte[] buffer;
    String serverIP = "192.168.0.16";
    int serverPORT = 10789;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("To server : ");
            str = sc.nextLine();
            if(str.equals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("exit");
                break;
            }
            buffer = str.getBytes();
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), serverPORT);
            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("sent message : " + str);
        } 
        socket.close();
    } catch (skip)
```

UDPserver:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

public static void main(String[] args){
    int port = 10789;
    DatagramSocket socket;
    DatagramPacket packet;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        while(true){
            socket.receive(packet);
            String text = new String(packet.getData());
            if(text.equals("exit")){
                System.out.println("exit");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("received : "+text);
        }
    }
```

When I put the input many times, The data of the packet is duplicated.

Example: While I was typing:

type `abcdeg`

displayed `abcdeg` at server

type `qwe`

displayed `qwedeg` at server

What is wrong? How to clean buffer?

Comment: In the client, `buffer` is still null when you call `buffer.length`, which should throw NPE. I suppose some code is missing?

Comment: I moved  `packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), serverPORT);` to the bottom of `buffer = str.getBytes();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server code the same buffer is reused for all the received packets (which is a good thing). However that means that data from previous packets is present in the buffer until it is overwritten. As you've seen, when you receive a packet that is shorter than the previous one, only the first bytes in the buffer are overwritten, up to the length of the received message.

`new String(packet.getData())` lets the String constructor figure out how long the data is by looking at the contents of the buffer. Instead, use [another constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int)) that lets you specify the length of the data: `new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength())`.

Comment: I understood and succeeded. really appreciate it. by the way. when received "exit" string at client, how to detect "exit" string? I added `if(text.equals("exit")){ System.out.println("exit") break; }` but nothing happened

Comment: while statement is still looping.

Comment: @H.Bin The problem is that when the user inputs "exit" at the client, the client exits immediately without sending the string to the server. To fix this you can put the `if(str.equals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("exit");
                break;
            }` block at the end of the client's while loop

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear the buffer from server side, as same buffer is used for all connection. However, you can use  `packet.getLength()` and `packet.getOffset()` to check the length and offset of received data.

```
String received 
          = new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```